# How to set the interval of points on X -Y Axis Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

I have lot's of data for plotting graphs for this resaon I am using Highcharts Boost. My data is in time series. For example as follows

```
[[1466685300000,170],[1466597700000,0],[1466512500000,161],[1466511300000,0],[1466426100000,165]]
```

And i am using highcharts boost, refrence link [highcharts boost area graph](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/studies/canvas-area/)

Now I want change x-y coordinates to time series format when graph plotting. I tried to change x-y coordinates but graph plotting default x-y coordinates. Please suggest me to how to change x-y coordinates?

Comment: I am not sure what you would like to achieve but I think that you need to add xAxis.type = 'datetime' in your chart options object. Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/48nfbrww/

Comment: Yes i want this only thank you so much @GrzegorzBlachliński..